# incorrect time slot when adding events on fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using 3.2.1 jquery, 2.17.1 moment, and 3.3.1 fullcalendar. When I click on a time slot to add an event in the day/week view, it uses the slot below it. It works if I use 2.6.1 fullcalendar version.

[image]

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: can you show it in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work now after making the calendar bigger. :/
thanks!